# How to write a shell script to ssh to a remote machine and run a few commands there

Tags: command-line, ssh, scripts, passwd

The flow of my actual requirement is as follows.

1. ssh from system1 to system2
2. Run the `passwd` command for the logged-in user in system2
3. Enter the preferred new password
4. Logout and throw a message [`Password had been updated
   successfully`]

I got steps for everything else but to change the password in the remote system is a bit confusing.

Pardon if the question is broad, and please support.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
foo@server1$ ssh -t bar@server2 'passwd && echo "Password updated sucessfully"'
```

The `-t` option forces pseudo tty allocation, otherwise your typed password will be seen on the screen.

Comment: @heemayi: This is okay, but what i need is a shell script which is capable of doing the following once run.  1: ssh to bar@server , 2:run 'passwd' command there, 3:Enter new password, 4:Return to foo@server.       The script itself should be capable of running this. Password can be supplied in the script itself.

Comment: @heemayi : Any suggessions...?